# What is this square bracket between staves?

Tags: piano, notation, sheet-music

I am trying to learn a piece of piano music and have found some strange notation in it.

[image: Two vertical brackets spanning the two piano staves, each to the right of a multi-stave chord.]

The two vertical brackets appear to apply only to that particular chord. I have not found this notation elsewhere in the piece nor have I encountered it before. The problematic notation is highlighted below:

[image: Freehand circles!]

What is this notation called? What does it mean?

Comment: It means "play all the bracketed notes with the same hand" - probably the left hand. (I assume you made this drawing yourself and left out the other notes in the score).

Comment: @alephzero Actually, I didn't. This is from the original and afaik so far only copy of the piece. I am transcribing it in order to be able to read it in real-time. Please post that as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means the bracketed notes are to be considered a single musical unit.  The composer is suggesting you play them all with the same hand.  This is probably a good idea, but in the absence of any further, higher notes, it's only a suggestion.   The composer gets to tell you what notes to play.  He doesn't get to insist on HOW you achieve it!