# Left hand/right hand indications LilyPond

Tags: lilypond, engraving

I have been skimming through the LilyPond documentation for quite some time now, and I cannot find the proper way to insert "left hand" or "right hand" indications with LilyPond.

Usually, when some notes that appear, say, above in the upper staff are nicely played by the left hand, it is customary to suggest it to the reader by means of a (square) bracket and the indication "left hand" or "l.h." (or "mano sinistra"/"m.s." in Italian) (similarly for right hand).

How do we do this using LilyPond?

Comment: For the brackets see: [What's this L symbol in piano notation called?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/76126/whats-this-l-symbol-in-piano-notation-called)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any pre-defined commands to do this. That's presumably because you can pretty easily just write in `\markup "m.s."` to quickly insert the command.

And since it's markup, you can add in whatever other specifications you like: `^` or `_` to specify direction, `\italic`, text sizes, alignment, and so on.