# What is this symbol that looks like an elongated "L" on the left-hand piano staff, and how can I write it in Musescore?

Tags: piano, notation, terminology, musescore

I'm writing out the Bärenreiter version of *Bach Concerto for two violins BWV 1043* on Musescore, and have come across an odd symbol in the left hand piano part.

Here is a picture - the elongated L symbol just before the G#:

[image: strange symbol]

At a guess, it looks like it is separating a voice, but I'm not sure what it's called so I can't find it in the Musescore palettes.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know the name, but it's definitely used to indicate that the note above the bottom crook of the line is played by the RH despite being written in the lower staff.

Comment: @PatMuchmore so I have just realised from looking at the number of rests in the RH!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As Pat correctly stated, this instructs the performer to play this music with the right hand.

You can find this bracket in MuseScore by opening up the Master Palette (press z to open it up). I recommend using the search feature and searching for "hand," and you should see the bracket there.

You may also find [this discussion](https://musescore.org/en/node/182291) on MuseScore's website helpful.

Comment: Well I never. That's handy...

Comment: There's also a flipped version for playing notes on the upper staff with the left hand.  You could get away with omitting them since the direction of the note stems also gives you the same information, but it never hurts to add clarity.