# How to add left/right hand fingering bracket to specific note group

Tags: lilypond, engraving

How can I replicate this LH left hand fingering annotation with Lilypond? The bracket around the lower three notes is the troublesome part. I've tried several approaches to no avail.

The original,

[image]

Using a custom dynamic script I've managed to insert the LH. However trying to add the line with `\draw-line` hasn't worked because the entire markup object is automatically shifted downward such that the lines cannot overlap the staff (it seems).

[image]

Dynamic script,

```
lh = \markup { \center-align \line { \hspace #-5 \normal-text \teeny LH } }
lhDynamic = #(make-dynamic-script lh)
```

**Update & Solution**

I found a solution based on [@ksnortum](https://music.stackexchange.com/users/18987/ksnortum)'s answer,
[image]

and the code,

```
lhMarkText = \markup { 
  \column {
    \vspace #1.65
    \path #0.12 #'((moveto 0 0)(rlineto -0.8 0)(rlineto 0 -3))
    \override #'(font-encoding . latin1) \lower #2 \right-align \teeny \smallCaps "LH" 
  }
}

% used within \relative {} like so
\set fingeringOrientations = #'(left)
<c\finger \lhMarkText>4|
```

Comment: You might check out this thread: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/lilypond-user/2010-09/msg00713.html.

Comment: That line is not a line connecting fingering indicator and head. It is a m.s.-Bracket, indicating up to which point the notes should be played with the left hand.

Comment: Related: [What's this L symbol in piano notation called?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/76126/whats-this-l-symbol-in-piano-notation-called)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the following code from [this conversation](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/lilypond-user/2014-10/msg00460.html).  Maybe you can adapt it to your needs:

```
\version "2.24.0"

% Hand indicators
%   Note: To use these correctly, the note MUST be part of a chord, even
%   if it's by itself, using, for example, the following syntax:
%
%   \set fingeringOrientations = #'(left)
%   <c\finger \lhMark>  % or \lhMarkText to add "l.h." to the mark
%
lhMarkText = \markup { 
  \concat {
    \override #'(font-encoding . latin1) \italic "l.h. " 
    \path #0.1 #'((moveto 0 -0.5)(rlineto 0 1.5)(rlineto 0.5 0))
  }
}
rhMarkText = \markup { 
  \concat {
    \override #'(font-encoding . latin1) \italic "r.h. " 
    \path #0.1 #'((moveto 0 1)(rlineto 0 -1.5)(rlineto 0.5 0))
  }
}
lhMark = \markup { 
  \path #0.1 #'((moveto -1 0)(rlineto 0 1.5)(rlineto 0.5 0))
}
rhMark = \markup { 
  \path #0.1 #'((moveto -1 0)(rlineto 0 -1.5)(rlineto 0.5 0))
}

\relative c'' {
  c4-1 
  d-2 
  \set fingeringOrientations = #'(left)
  <c\finger \lhMarkText f>\finger \markup \tied-lyric "4~3" 
  <c\finger \rhMark>\finger "2 - 3"
}
```